# vmware/Parallels and Backtrack 5

Tags: vmware, backtrack, parallels

After endless hours of debugging and trying different things, I can't seem to get Backtrack 5 R3 to cooperate as guest OS on my OSX Lion host. What I'm trying to do is to setup BT as guest OS on my Lion and then use my Alfa AWUS036NH with it.

- My adapter is supported by BT
- I am able to use it on VMware on Windows, but it's a major pain and I need it on my mac
- My adapter is installed and working on OSX just fine
- BT does not indicate it at all, I ran lsusb and it doesn't even show it (either running on VMware or Parallels)
- I tried both live CD and full install, still no luck
- I have the USB modules installed and set up, no dice
- Both of virtual machines pick up a USB storage device just fine

What could be the reason behind it not working? I've been wrapping my head around this for two weeks now, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you enable [USB pass-through](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vmadmin.doc_41/vsp_vm_guide/configuring_virtual_machines/c_configuring_usb_passthrough_devices.html) for the device?

Comment: Evan, i'm not sure where exactly I should do that? Here is a screenshot of my USB settings for that machine http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/1816/rm.png when I try to tick the tick box next to my ralink adapter it doesn't do anything tho?

Comment: If the device is set to 'Connect to Linux' on plugin, you should be able to see it. Check the output of `dmesg`. Do you see anything related to the adapter?

Comment: Have you tried Kali instead? It's based on Debian stable instead the old Ubuntu 10.04. It's a long shot, but maybe it's worth.